# How can I identify a radio button from the click event of a button that has been included within the template for that radio button

Tags: windows-phone-7, event-handling, radio-button, controltemplate

This for a Windows Phone 7 app and here is the template code that I am using:

```
<Style x:Key="RadioButtonStyle1" BasedOn="{StaticResource PhoneRadioButtonCheckBoxBase}" TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="EnabledCheckBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedDarkCheckBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedLightCheckBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxCheckBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="EnabledCheckBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledDarkCheckBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledLightCheckBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxCheckDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetLargeOverhang}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="32"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="EnabledCheckBackground" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" IsHitTestVisible="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="32"/>
                            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="{StaticResource PhoneDarkThemeOpacity}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="32">
                                <Ellipse x:Name="PressedDarkCheckBackground" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxPressedBrush}" Height="32" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="32"/>
                                <Ellipse x:Name="DisabledDarkCheckBackground" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxDisabledBrush}" Height="32" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="32"/>
                            </Canvas>
                            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="{StaticResource PhoneLightThemeOpacity}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="32">
                                <Ellipse x:Name="PressedLightCheckBackground" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxPressedBrush}" Height="32" Stroke="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" StrokeThickness="{StaticResource PhoneStrokeThickness}" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="32"/>
                                <Ellipse x:Name="DisabledLightCheckBackground" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxDisabledBrush}" Height="32" Stroke="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" StrokeThickness="{StaticResource PhoneStrokeThickness}" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="32"/>
                            </Canvas>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="CheckMark" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxCheckBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="12,0,146,-2" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Button Content="Play" Margin="0,0,2,-1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="159" Click="PlayButton_Click"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I want to create one click event that each button will use but from within that event handler I need to be able to identify the Radio Button containing the button being clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably "better" ways to achieve what you're trying to do but you can cast the `sender`, that is passed to the click event handler, to a `FrameworkElement` and then you can access it's `DataContext` which you can then cast appropriately to get whatever information you require about the item in question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've used the Tree helper and was able then to navigate to the parent to get the information that I wanted.